# Using java to open a web browser on another computer

Tags: java, external

So, this is a rather unusual question, and I can't find anything else anywhere which has been helpful on how to do this, or if its even possible to do so.

I'm working on a game server wrote in java, and I'm trying to get the users default web browser to open to a specific link, when a command is typed into the chat box and sent to the server.

The current Issue I have is, when a user issues the command, it opens the browser on the host system, and not the players system.

I haven't been able to try any other methods, as I am unable to find any information regarding my specific situation!

```java
@CommandHandlerMethod(accessLevel = EAccessLevel.USER)
    public static Object[] vote(final Player player, final String... params) {
        try {
            Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
            URI oURL = new URI("www.example.com");
            desktop.browse(oURL);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return AbstractCommandHandler.getAcceptResult("");
    }
```

What I was hoping for via this code, was to open the web browser on the players system to allow them to view a specific webpage, but this has not been the case, and opens it on the server host system.

Comment: Have you taken a look at Java RMI?

Comment: You cannot run a program on a given machine without the cooperation of that machine.  The server needs to send some kind of signal or command to the client, over their communication link, to which the client responds by opening a browser locally.  Or maybe the client proactively recognizes the command in the chat stream and handles it directly, without the server's involvement.

Comment: A possible (and probably much simpler) workaround would be the following: the client issues the command, then waits (asynchronously) for a specific response from the server. Once the correct response arrives, the client itself opens the web browser.

Comment: *"You cannot run a program on a given machine without the cooperation of that machine."* - And if you could do that, it would be a major security flaw.  Even (just) opening a browser window.  Think about it!  Reconsider what you are trying to do here.

Comment: *"when a command is typed into the chat box"* What chat box? What is running on the client, presenting a chat box to the user?

Comment: You should add these codes to the game client rather than the game server.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and feedback everyone, I will be implementing this with RMI suggested by vs97!